# Modernizer for Gulp and Elixir

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, laravel-5

I am really working hard to finalizing my gulp file so that I have a css and js files for my frontend of my Laravel application and also for the backend. Right now this is what I am down to for the most part in my head section of my layout file. Is there anything further I can do or any suggestions that can be made to best assist this situation.

My question is there any way of me adding those to a separate js script file since I can't add it to my regular backend.js file since these files belong in the head of my page. The only reason why I'm questioning that is because of the if statements that are apart of this.

Also how can I add the google fonts link to my css file that's created in my gulp file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/backend.css') }}">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,300italic'>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="../../../global/vendor/html5shiv/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
<script src="../../../global/vendor/media-match/media.match.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../global/vendor/respond/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="../../../global/vendor/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="../../../global/vendor/breakpoints/breakpoints.js"></script>
<script>
Breakpoints();
</script>
```

Anyone have an idea how I should handle this?